# Not able to Replaying tweet using Tweetinvi

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

```
    // 1. /*Authentication */

    TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials("", "", "", "");

    var tweets = SearchJson.SearchTweets("@Kaanshu7");
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var tweetsSerialize = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(tweets);
    var text = tweetsSerialize["statuses"][0]["text"];
    bool isAvailable = text.Contains("#ServiceRequest");
    if (isAvailable)
    {
        tweet = text;
        tweet_id = tweetsSerialize["statuses"][0]["id"];


        // 2. /*Here trying to Retweet (not posting)*/

        retweet = Console.ReadLine();
        var ReplyTweet = Tweet.CreateTweet(retweet);
        var replyTweet = Tweet.PublishTweetInReplyTo(ReplyTweet, tweet_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

why is your code so complex when it could be as east as the following:

```
var tweets = Search.SearchTweets("@Kaanshu7");
var firstTweet = tweets.First();
bool isAvailable = firstTweet.Text.Contains("#ServiceRequest");

if (isAvailable)
{
    var retweetMessage = Console.ReadLine();
    firstTweet.PublishReply(retweetMessage);
}
```

Easier don't you think?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. i am using LinqtoTwitter library and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the twitter API changed, and to reply tweets with tweetinv, you need to do that:

```
var tweet = Search.SearchTweets("stackoverflow");
var textToPublish = $"@{tweet.CreatedBy.ScreenName}";
var reply = Tweet.PublishTweet(new PublishTweetParameters(textToPublish)
                {
                    InReplyToTweet = tweet
                });
```